# Screen record with audio (flutter )

Tags: android, flutter

How to screen record particular widget in flutter with audio?

I found two packages :-
1-screen_recorder ==>but it didn't record audio .
flutter_screen_recording ==> record all the screen but I want to record only particular widget.

So is there any other package that can be used?

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.